# Obtaining scree plot from dimension reduction in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am performing dimension reduction on a set of variables with local collinearity (to be able to use them in a GWR).
The tool help on the Esri website indicates a scree plot will be generated with the eigenvalue output table but I cannot seem to locate it. Does anyone know where I can find the scree plot output after running the tool?

Comment: Can you share the URL of the Tool Help? Are you referring to the Dimension Reduction Tool Help?

Comment: Yes the dimension reduction tool - https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/dimensionreduction.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scree plots are made as stand-alone tables at the bottom of the contents pane in ArcGIS Pro